# JSP errors, disable in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have Eclipse, the Juno release.  Just recently I am getting a few JSP errors which aren't valid or I don't care to see.  Examples of the errors are below.

```
The function fn:replace is undefined
Attribute (cellpadding) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents.
```

The function error is not valid, as it working perfectly fine when I run the web application.  I simple don't care the HTML5 related obsolete messages.  I'd like Eclipse to not display these "errors".

I've tried enabling project specific validations, and turning off the HTML, JSP, & Tag validators, but it made no difference.

Comment: Just as an FYI.  I am on a distributed project.  A coworker altered our project's POM file, and the HTML5 "errors" went away.  I would imagine someone erroneously added an HTML5 dependency to the project, which was corrected.  However, the function undefined error is still displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean that your project is using using older type of (x)html. If you don't like Eclipse falling by default to HTML5, go to project properties, then Web Content Settings, then in Document Type select the one you use.